# datetime conversion using python

Tags: python, datetime

I have date as

```
'Apr, 2012'
```

I want to convert it to the "mx datetime" object.

Can anyone tell me how to convert the same?

Comment: Presumably you are talking about the [eGenix mxDateTime](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/) library, rather than Python's built-in `datetime` module.

Comment: What have you tried?  I believe the mx `strptime` function works the same as the python stdlib's `datetime.datetime.strptime` function, so this should be a very straight forward operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dateutil.parser to parse dates to python datetime objects:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from mx.DateTime import DateFrom
date = DateFrom(parse('Apr, 2012'))
```

Comment: I am looking for "mx datetime objects"